# Phonegap hates my blinking message

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

i'm new here ^^ Can you help me?

I've developed a very easy phonegap code-app.
- First step: I've written this two lines in the cmd:
`phonegap create Test`
`bower install bootstrap` (this adds bootstrap and jquery).
- Second step: I've edited the content of index.html, index.js and I've written:

```js
window.onload = function() {blink()};

function blink() {
    $("#logo").fadeOut(500);
    $("#logo").fadeIn(500);
    $("#logo").fadeOut(500);
    $("#logo").fadeIn(500);
    window.setTimeout(link,2050);
}

function link(){
    window.open("../www/otherpage.html","_self");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="bower_components\jquery\dist\jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/www/js/index.js"></script>
  <style>
  body {
      font: 20px sans-serif;
      line-height: 1.8;
      color: #f5f6f7;
      background-color: #0068ff;
  }
  p {font-size: 16px;}
  .margin {margin-bottom: 40px;}
  .bg-1 { 
      background-color: #0068ff;
      color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- First Container -->
<div class="container-fluid bg-1 text-center">
    <center><h1>This is a Title<br>Hello!</h1><div id="logo">Blinking message</div></center>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

- Third step: I've written in the cmd:
`phonegap build android`
- Fourth step: I've tested the apk in my tablet and my phone, but the message doesn't blink and the page doesn't goes on by linking me to the other html page. What's wrong?
Thanks!!!

Comment: Looks like it can't load some JavaScript resources, either index.js or the ones in bower_components. Or both.

Comment: As simple as that :( I feel so dumb. The js wasn't loading. Thank you, MaxArt.

Comment: Don't ever feel dumb. Missing things is something very common when getting into new stuff, even for experienced developers (in other areas). But if I could suggest a thing, the title of your post here on StackOverflow shouldn't be so colloquial: it should describe briefly and as technically as possible your problem. The body of the post, though, is clear and descriptive. Keep it up!

Comment: Thank you again, MaxArt. I'll work on it